# Exactly what SelectMany() is for?

Tags: c#, enumerable

It's hard to explain this without input and output. I made into a simple Car example to avoid unnecessary details of my project.

I have this list:

```
List<car> cars = new List<car>()
{
    new car() { carname = "bmw", carwheels = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 } },
    new car() { carname = "cadillac", carwheels = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 } },
    new car() { carname = "mustang", carwheels = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 } }
};
```

I want to output this with extension classes:

```
{
    { carname = "bmw", carwheel = 1 },
    { carname = "bmw", carwheel = 2 },
    { carname = "bmw", carwheel = 3 },
    { carname = "bmw", carwheel = 4 },
    { carname = "cadillac", carwheel = 1 },
    { carname = "cadillac", carwheel = 2 },
    { carname = "cadillac", carwheel = 3 },
    { carname = "cadillac", carwheel = 4 },
    { carname = "mustang", carwheel = 1 },
    { carname = "mustang", carwheel = 2 },
    { carname = "mustang", carwheel = 3 },
    { carname = "mustang", carwheel = 4 }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with a projection by IEnumerable extension methods? Something that acts like the opposite of SelectMany().

Comment: Why opposite, isn't it exactly what `SelectMany` does?

Comment: @TimSchmelter -- to my understanding, `SelectMany()` would take the bottom list and flatten it into singles, each with a list of car wheels. Is there another overload to SelectMany() I should learn?

Comment: This is not the opposite of `SelectMany`, this *is* `SelectMany`.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the "opposite" of `SelectMany` would be `GroupBy`. In this case you could `GroupBy` the result by `carname` and then create an instance of `car` for every group to get your original list.

Comment: @TimSchmelter -- I see your point. Yeah, I think I misled everyone with this title of the question. I think I've been looking at code for too long :).Rene's answer is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the *opposite* of `SelectMany()`, but exactly what `SelectMany()` is for. You can achieve this like that:

```
var result = cars.SelectMany(c => 
            c.carwheels.Select(w => new 
            {
                carname = c.carname,
                carwheel = w
            })).ToList();
```

The inner `Select` projects the wheels of each car to a new object (in my code of an anonymous type with your specified properties). And the outer `SelectMany()` flattens these sequences into one list.

Comment: yes that's been spinning my head for a while and you're right -- sorry for my misleading title. This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 4):

That's one of the rare cases where I find the verbose Linq syntax more readable:

```
 var query = from car in cars
             from carwheel in car.carwheels
             select new { car.carname, carwheel };
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this solution will be helpfull? This will split your IEnumerable to IEnumerable of fixed size IEnumerable

```
public static class EnumerableExtension
{
    private static IEnumerable<T> GetChunk<T>(IEnumerator<T> source, int size)
    {
        yield return source.Current;

        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (source.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return source.Current;
            }
            else
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitToChunks<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int size)
    {
        if (size < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return GetChunk(enumerator, size);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Sorry, haven't read the question properly)